# MySQL - Get Max row for each customer from each table and provide results of those that meet criteria

Tags: mysql

I am working on a system where we have customer data split up across a variety of tables. As an example (simplified):

Customer Status

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stan | active |
| 2 | Danny | closed |
| 3 | Elle | active |
| 4 | Stan | active |

Account Status

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stan | good standing |
| 2 | Danny | good standing |
| 3 | Elle | good standing |
| 4 | Stan | in arrears |
| 5 | Stan | good standing |
| 6 | Elle | in arrears |

Order Status

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stan | Ordered |
| 2 | Danny | Ordered |
| 3 | Elle | Pending |
| 4 | Stan | Completed |
| 5 | Stan | Pending |
| 6 | Elle | Ordered |

If I wanted to identify all customers that are:

- Customer Status: Active
- Account Status: In arrears
- Order Status: Pending

In the above example, the only returned name should be Stan

I've been attempting SQL such as this, but realised it's selecting not the max, but the max that has my filter:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_status c
WHERE c.id = (SELECT MAX(c2.id) FROM customer_status c2 WHERE c2.name  = c.name) AND c.status = "active"
AND c.name in (SELECT name FROM account_status as WHERE as.id = (SELECT MAX(as2.id) FROM account_status as2 WHERE as.name = as2.name) AND as.active = "in arrears")
AND c.name in (SELECT name FROM order_status os WHERE os.id = (SELECT MAX(os.id) FROM order_status os2 WHERE os.name = os2.name) AND os.status = "Pending")
```

What I've realised is that the rows being returned for account status and order status is the highest ID with the provided status, whereas I'd like to get the last row for each customer and then only pass them back if they have the right status.

Is this where I need to use Joins instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a simple join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM customer_status c
INNER JOIN account_status as ON c.name  = as.name
INNER JOIN order_status os ON c.name = os.name
 WHERE c.status = "active"
   AND as.active = "in arrears"
   AND os.status = "Pending"
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of the old join syntax. It makes complex queries unreadable. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)